# how to remove all double quotes from csv except specific field

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, perl

I want to remove all double quotes from my csv but not the fourth field (because the four fields represent PATH of file)

Please advice how to implement this by **sed** or **awk** or **perl one liner** , etc

What I know for now is to use simple sed command as:

```
   sed s"/\"//g"  file.csv  | sed 's/ //g'
```

but this command no so elegant and also work on the fourth field ( fourth field should not be edit )

**Remark - need also to delete empty spaces between quotes to near character**

Example ( file csv before )

```
"24  ","COsc   ","LINUX","/VP/Ame/AR/Celts/COf","  fbsutamante ",fbu2012,"kkk","&^#$@J  ",,,,,
25,COsc,LINUX,"/VP/Ame/AR/Celts/COf","fbsutamante ",fbu2012,"iiii ","   *****",,,,,
```

Example ( file csv after after )

```
24,COsc,LINUX,"/VP/Ame/AR HR/Ce   lts/COf",fbsutamante,fbu2012,kkk,&^#$@J,,,,,
25,COsc,LINUX,"/VP/Ame/AR HR/Ce   lts/COf",fbsutamante,fbu2012,iiii,*****,,,,,
```

Comment: With GNU `sed`: `sed 's/\s*"\s*//3g'`

Comment: if you want please add this answer and I will test this

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas note it has to apply to 1st to 3rd and 5th to the end. Does `3g` match like this?

Comment: see my update - yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}              # set input and output field separator as comma
     {for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {       # loop from 5th field
            gsub("\"","", $i);      # remove "
            gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"", $i); # remove leading spaces
            gsub(/[ \t]+$/,"",$i)}  # remove trailing spaces
     }1' file
```

Removing leading and trailing is based on this answer by BMW: [Remove Leading and trailing space in field in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601998/1983854).

#### Test

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {gsub("\"","", $i); gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"", $i); gsub(/[ \t]+$/,"",$i)}}1' file
24,COsc,LINUX,"/VP/Ame/AR/Celts/COf",fbsutamante,fbu2012,kkk,&^#$@J,,,,,
25,COsc,LINUX,"/VP/Ame/AR/Celts/COf",fbsutamante,fbu2012,iiii,*****,,,,,
```

---

If it also have to clean 1st to 3rd fields, just add `if (i!=4)` and loop through all the fields:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (i!=4) {gsub("\"","", $i); gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"", $i); gsub(/[ \t]+$/,"",$i)}}}1' a
24,COsc,LINUX,"/VP/Ame/AR/Celts/COf",fbsutamante,fbu2012,kkk,&^#$@J,,,,,
25,COsc,LINUX,"/VP/Ame/AR/Celts/COf",fbsutamante,fbu2012,iiii,*****,,,,,
```

Comment: one remark - sorry for this update - but quotes can be also in the first , sec , thired field ( see my update )

Comment: @maihabunash ok, then see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove them all and then put them back:

```
sed 's/"//g;s/,/,"/3;s/,/",/4'
```